# ActiveRecord DateTime comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I understand that Rails store the Time in UTC.

I have out_date and in_date instances of DateTime

I have this query:

```
reservations = Reservation.where("bookable_id = :bookable_id AND bookable_type = :bookable_type AND status <> :status AND ((:out_date >= check_out_date AND  :out_date <= check_in_date) OR (:in_date <= check_in_date AND :in_date >= check_out_date) OR (:out_date <= check_in_date AND :in_date >= check_in_date))", :bookable_id => params[:bookable_id], :bookable_type => params[:bookable_type], :status => Reservation::STATUS_CHECKED_IN, :out_date => out_date, :in_date => in_date)
```

I always get a null set even though I should get a return tuple.

I have tried these varients:

```
out_date.utc

out_date.utc.to_s(:db)
```

Nothing seems to be working. How to construct this query?

Controller Code:

```
  in_date = DateTime.strptime params[:checkin], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
  out_date = DateTime.strptime params[:checkout], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"

  #check collision with non-recurring reservations
  reservations = Reservation.where("bookable_id = :bookable_id AND bookable_type = :bookable_type AND status <> :status AND ((:out_date >= check_out_date AND  :out_date <= check_in_date) OR (:in_date <= check_in_date AND :in_date >= check_out_date) OR (:out_date <= check_in_date AND :in_date >= check_in_date))", :bookable_id => params[:bookable_id], :bookable_type => params[:bookable_type], :status => Reservation::STATUS_CHECKED_IN, :out_date => out_date, :in_date => in_date)
  logger.info(reservations)
  if !reservations.empty?
    @error_message = "This Asset has already been reserved for those dates"
    return
  end
```

Also on the Rails Console, the simpler query fails:

```
1.9.3p0 :007 > Reservation.find_by_id 31
  Reservation Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`id` = 31 LIMIT 1
 => #<Reservation id: 31, bookable_id: 11, bookable_type: "Asset", user_id: 1, check_out_date: "2012-07-07 08:00:00", check_in_date: "2012-07-07 10:00:00", notes: "rec", status: "Ready", is_recurring: true, repeat_count: 5>


1.9.3p0 :009 > Reservation.where " ? >= check_out_date AND ? <= check_in_date",DateTime.new(2012,7,7,9),DateTime.new(2012,7,7,9)
  Reservation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE ( '2012-07-07 09:00:00' >= check_out_date AND '2012-07-07 09:00:00' <= check_in_date)
 => []
```

Comment: Where is the `out_date` variable assigned?

Comment: Also, you should be using [Named Scopes](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: @SimoneCarletti In the same controller.

Comment: Post the entire controller content or at least the relevant sections. We can't tell you why a variable is `nil` if we can't see where and how it is assigned.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Here you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was because of the the database time being stored in UTC and the local time being different and not satisfying the query condition.

Answer (score 1):

I read the updated code and, apparently, it's correct. Make sure the `out_date` and `in_date` are `DateTime` objects and not null objects.

You don't need to format the query, it should be handled for you.

If you want to debug the query SQL, you can use the `.to_sql`

```
reservations = Reservation.where("...") # your query
puts reservation.to_sql
# => "SELECT ..."
```

Print the query and check if the value is correctly formatted.

Comment: I get this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reservations` WHERE (bookable_id = '11' AND bookable_type = 'Asset' AND status <> 'Checked In' AND (('2012-07-07 09:00:00' >= check_out_date AND '2012-07-07 09:00:00' <= check_in_date) OR ('2012-07-07 11:00:00' <= check_in_date AND '2012-07-07 11:00:00' >= check_out_date) OR ('2012-07-07 09:00:00' <= check_in_date AND '2012-07-07 11:00:00' >= check_in_date)))

Comment: This seems to be fine. If the check_in_date and check_out_date are being handled by rails. Why am I getting no result?

Comment: At this point, the issue is the query itself. Try starting with a simpler query, then add one condition at time and see where it fails.

Comment: I constructed a very simple query and it fails as well. Check the edit snip please. Why is this happening?

Comment: Not referring to error but it does not return the dataset which accurately satisfies the conditions. For the 2nd query running shouldnt I get the Reservation instance with id 31?

Comment: Invert the condition. First the field, then the value. `check_out_date <= ?` or make sure your database supports this order. This is not a Rails issue, it's an issue with your query.

Comment: Inverting dosent help. I am using mysql. What could be wrong? The query is already known and looks perfect.